# Cypher returns exponential count result on 'join'

Tags: database, graph, neo4j, cypher

I am learning Cypher on Neo4j and I am having trouble in understanding how to perform an efficient 'join' equivalent in Cypher.

I am using the standard Matrix character example and I have added some nodes to the mix called 'Gun' with a relation of ':GIVEN_TO'. You can see the console with my query result here:

http://console.neo4j.org/r/rog2hv

The query I am using is:

`MATCH (Neo:Crew { name: 'Neo' })-[:KNOWS*..]->(other:Crew),(other)<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun),(Neo)<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g2:Gun)
RETURN count(g2);`

I have given Neo 4 guns, but when I perform the above I get a count of '12'. This seems to be the case because there are 3 'others' and 3*4 = 12. So I get some exponential result.

What should my query look like to get the correct count ('4') from the example?

Edit:
The reason I am not querying through Guns directly as suggested by @ceej is because in my real use case I have to do this traversal as described above. Adding `DISTINCT` does not do anything for my result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get 12 guns instead of 4 is because your query produces a cartesian product. This is because you have asked for items in the same match statement without *joining* them.  @ceej rightly pointed out if you want to find Neo's guns you would do as he suggested in his first query.

If you wanted to get a list of the crew members and their guns then you could do something like this...

```
MATCH (crew:Crew)<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun)
RETURN crew.name, collect(g.name)
```

Which finds all of the crew members with guns and returns their name and the guns that they were given.

If you wanted to invert it and get a list of the guns and the respective crew members they were give to you could do the following...

```
MATCH (crew:Crew)<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun)
RETURN g.name, collect(crew.name)
```

If you wanted to find all of the crew that knew Neo multiple levels deep that were given a gun you could write the query like this...

```
MATCH (crew:Crew)<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun)
WITH crew, g
MATCH (neo:Crew {name: 'Neo'})-[:KNOWS*0..]->(crew)
RETURN crew.name, collect(g.name)
```

That finds all the crew that were given guns and then determines which of them have a `:KNOWS` path to Neo.

Comment: Thank you, that already comes close to my actual use case, which, granted, I should have laid out better. Now my remaining question is how I would get all the actual gun nodes that were given to crew members who know Neo any number of levels deep? So people who know people who know Neo, etc. `[:KNOWS*..]` and: would it also be possible to include those crew nodes as well?

Comment: I managed to get the result here: http://console.neo4j.org/r/25or9h but it seems like it isn't the best way to achieve this. Any thoughts?

Comment: Yes, there is a better way. I updated the answer with another query that returns guns of crew that know Neo.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dave! That is exactly what I needed. And in my real database it is really really fast (160ms having 3 matches (one extra relationship level) on over 300_000 records). Very excited :)

Answer (score 2):

Forgive me, but I am am unclear why you have the initial `MATCH` in your query. From your explanation it would appear that you are trying to get the number of `:Gun` nodes linked to `Neo` by the `:GIVEN_TO` relationship. In which case all you need is the latter part of your query. Which would give you something like

```
MATCH (neo:Crew { name: 'Neo' })<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun)
RETURN count(g)
```

Furthermore, to make sure that you are only counting distinct `:Gun` nodes you can add `DISTINCT` to the `RETURN` statement.

```
MATCH (neo:Crew { name: 'Neo' })<-[:GIVEN_TO]-(g:Gun)
RETURN count( DISTINCT g )
```

This is possibly unnecessary in your case but can be helpful when the pattern that you are matching on can arrive at the same node by different traversals.

Have I misunderstood your requirement?

Comment: In reality I am not trying to count the guns. I am trying to get a result set of all crew members and their guns. The reason I am asking through a count and doing it through the people known by Neo is because I want to get the correct count despite going through the known contacts. I will try to make this more clear in the question.